# Could English speakers define from which country their interlocutor?

Tags: dialects

Could English speakers define from which English-speaking country their interlocutor (USA, England, Australia, Canada)?

Comment: I live in  the US.  Sometimes I can recognize Canadian accents, but usually not.  Accents from England and Australia are easier for me to recognize.  Other recognizable accents might be Scotland, South Africa, India.  Actors in movies may have dialect coaches to help them get the proper accent for the part they are playing.

Comment: Sometimes, sometimes not.  Depends a lot on how good the foreign speaker's English is, and on whether the individual listening was raised in an area of "normal" English dialect or some regional one.

Comment: Your question is lacking a verb like *comes from* at the end, so it is ungrammatical. Do you just want to know whether they cann tell where another native speaker ***IS*** from upon hearing that person speak?

Answer (score 1):

for most British English speakers:

- USA - recognisable. Canada - probably not distinguished from USA.
- Australia - recognisable. New Zealand - probably not distinguished
  from Australia.
- South Africa - recognisable, although might be confused with
  Australia.
- India, Pakistan, and similar - recognisable, but might not be
  distinguished

Comment: I'd add Singaporeans and Malaysians as another grouping that's distinguishable from the other groups but usually not from each other.

Comment: I would be able to distinguish a South African from an Australian - though perhaps not an Australian from a New Zealander, nor a South African from a Zimbabwean. But inside Britain itself one can tell a Liverpool person from a Manchester person even though the two cities are only 39 miles apart.

Comment: And of course there's oriental.  Some people would be able to distinguish Chinese from Japanese, say, while others would not.  And some people would be able to further distinguish some SE Asian accents.  I went to college with a guy from Vietnam, and at the time I could probably distinguish that accent pretty well.  (But that was 50 years ago.)

Comment: @HotLicks One can easily distinguish a Chinese from a Japanese when they speak English. It is far less easy to distinguish them if they are silent in front of you. Though if they are wearing clothes etc. you can make an intelligent guess. However if they each appeared naked it would be impossible to say which was which.

Answer (score 1):

From having spoken, almost every day, with foreigners from all over the world for 40 years, it is possible to pick out cadences, grammatical structures, vowel sounds, and idiosyncrasies and have a good guess as to which country, and often which area, the speaker comes from. However, the vast majority of English people do not have both this exposure **and** the knowledge of where a speaker comes from: both are needed to allow them to develop the skill. -- I hope you realise that you are speaking to a forum composed of people with a deep interest in language, and that we are unrepresentative and likely to have a skill that is at least similar to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the life experiences of the "English speaker".

English speakers who have had limited contact with other native speakers are probably dependent on Hollywood movies, and that is immediately problematic for obvious reasons.

On the other hand, those who have spent (or misspent) their youths on travel (to broaden the mind) will have encountered many other accents. More than that, native speakers living as ex-pats and working with other native-like speakers will have found so many variations of accent...that they have learned to put more attention to pronunciation to decode.

I remember once, as an American, I had to interpret between a woman from Liverpool, and a guy from Glasgow...as they both came from the same kingdom I was  little frustrated.

This question is possibly too broad.

Comment: Seems a bit mean to mention the island bit.

Comment: @tchrist sorry if i offended...will re-phrase.